# Receiving an $injector:unpr error when using ngResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-resource, ngresource

I am using ngResource and $resource instead of $http in my project. When I switched over to $resource, I received an $injector:unpr error when I ran the program. I checked to make sure that everything was spelled right. Additionally, I made sure that I called it in the HTML.

Here is the module:

```
angular.module('confusionApp', ['ui.router', 'ngResource'])
```

Here is the service I am trying to use:

```
angular.module('confusionApp')
  .constant("baseURL","http://localhost:3000/")
  .service('menuService', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function($resource, baseURL) {
     this.getDishes = function() {
        return $resource(baseURL+"dishes/:id", null, {
            'update':{
                method:'PUT'
            }
        });

    };
```

Here is where I call the function:

```
angular.module('confusionApp')
  .controller('MenuController', ['$scope', 'menuService', function($scope, menuService) {
        $scope.showMenu = true;
        $scope.message = "Loading ...";
        $scope.dishes = menuService.getDishes().query();
```

Here is the HTML scripts:

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: have you refered tha controller and service files

Comment: I created a plunker here and am not seeing any injectr error https://plnkr.co/edit/dbzDIyT0zOUZTSIZfzNs?p=preview. Please post the exact error you're getting.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/jxMkqlN.png

Comment: above is a link to the picture of the error

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was not actually with any of the code itself. The version of angular I was using was out of date compared to the version of angular-resource I had installed. I fixed this by deleting the dependency in the bower.json and then I removed the folder from bower_components. Then I redownloaded angular-resource with a specification of the version I wanted.

```
$ bower install angular-resource#1.4.8
```